# Why can't I append a char to an empty list in Python?

Tags: python, list, exception

In a program I am writing to create a list of words from a list of chars, I am getting a "list index out of range" exception.

```
def getlist(filename):
  f = open('alice.txt','r')
  charlist = f.read()
  wordlist = []
  done = False

  while(not done):
    j = 0
    for i in range(0,len(charlist)):
      if charlist[i] != ' ' and charlist[i] != '\n':
        wordlist[j] +=  charlist[i] 
      else: j+= 1
      done = i == len(charlist)-1
  return wordlist
```

So I started playing around with how lists work, and found that:

```
list = ['cars']
list[0]+= '!'
```

gives `list = ['cars!']`

However, with:

```
list = []
list[0]+= '!'
```

I get an out of bounds error. Why doesn't it do what seems logical: `list= ['!']`? How can I solve this? If I must initialize with something, how will I know the required size of the list? Are there any better, more conventional, ways to do what I'm attempting?

Comment: The easy way to get what you want is `wordlist = charlist.split()`.

Comment: The append is what you are working for. However what you are actually asking is why does the '!' get "appened" to the list when it has something in it and  not and empty list. Well in one you have the word cars in it. So when you say list[0] you are not actually asking for the list back but the string 'cars' so you are adding "!" to it. if you ask for list[0] with nothing in it, list does not have anything in it. Thats why you see the bounds error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`['cars']` is a list containing one element. That element is the string `'cars'`, which contains 4 characters.

`list[0] += '!'` actually does 3 separate things. The `list[0]` part selects the element of `list` at position 0. The `+=` part both concatenates the two strings (like `'cars' + '!'` would), and stores the resulting string back in the 0th slot of `list`.

When you try to apply that to the *empty* list, it fails at the "selects the element at position 0" part, because there is no such element. You are expecting it to behave as if you had not the empty list, but rather `['']`; the list containing **one** element which is the empty **string**. You can easily append `!` onto the end of an empty string, but in your example you don't have an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

To add to a list, including an an empty one, use the [`append()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method:

```
>>> mylist = []
>>> mylist.append('!')
>>> mylist
['!']
```

Comment: It's kind of funny that the question is "Why can't I append" and the answer is "use `.append()`". :^)

Answer (score 0):

> However, with:
>
> ```
> list = []
> list[0]+= '!'
> ```
>
> I get an out of bounds error. Why doesn't it do what seems logical:
>   `list= ['!']`?

Because that *isn't* logical in Python. To append `'!'` to `list[0]`, `list[0]` has to exist in the first place. It will not magically turn into an empty string for you to concatenate the exclamation mark to. In the general case, Python would not have a way to figure out what kind of "empty" element to magic up, anyway.

The `append` method is provided on lists in order to append an element to the list. However, what you're doing is **massively** over-complicating things. If all you want is a list consisting of the words in the file, that is as easy as:

```
def getlist(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read().split()
```

Comment: The reason I'm not doing this is that the text has elements like: ',' ,  '.' ,  'alice--didn't' , etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not from the statement `list[0]+= '!'`, its from accessing an empty list which is out of range error :

```
>>> my_list = list()
>>> my_list[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

And `+=` is not used for appending in a list, its for concatenating a string or numeric addition and internally its calling the following method.

```
__iadd__(...)
    x.__iadd__(y) <==> x+=y
```